# Exclude or prioritize suggestions in PyCharm code completion?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, autocomplete, pycharm, autosuggest

How do i exclude or decrease priority for certain suggestions? i use
`self` most inside a method. But i always have to type `self` fully because PyCharm keeps suggesting `select` from `..\DLLs\select.pyd`. I've never used or imported `select` in my project.

Similarly, I want `return` to be top priority instead of `re` from regular expressions module. (`re` module is not used in my project). My question may be linked to these question:

- [Pycharm code completion suggest not imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274258/pycharm-code-completion-suggest-not-imported-modules)
- [PyCharm: Why does `audioop` get prefered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352610/pycharm-why-does-audioop-get-prefered)

An acceptable solution might be an option in PyCharm like [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/excluding-classes-from-auto-import/) or [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/guide/tips/exclude-from-imports-and-completion/) or [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Auto-Completing_Code.html)

[image: PyCharm code completion]

*PyCharm 2021.2.2* on Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: Why does \`audioop\` get prefered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352610/pycharm-why-does-audioop-get-prefered)

Comment: @bad_coder No, i guess. The question is similar but not exactly the answer my question seeks to. What i want is similar to [this feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/guide/tips/exclude-from-imports-and-completion/)

Comment: Problem is your first sentence: *"(...) or decrease priority"* which is not about excluding but sorting. To that end the linked duplicate target.

Comment: @bad_coder I edited my question to add more clarification to what i want

Comment: According to Stack Overflow rules you can only ask 1 question per post. You just edited your question to ask 2 separate questions: 1º excluding, 2º sorting. That is reason for closing the question as *"Need more focus"*, please consider the guidelines [*"Why are some questions closed??"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I suggest removing the part about sorting which is adequately answered in the other thread.

Comment: @bad_coder All i want is to appear `self` and `return` to be my top suggestion instead of `select` and `re`.  Whether the solution is achieved by excluding or decreasing the priority (_sorting_ as you termed) of unwanted suggestion, is not a matter of concern to the question. and I couldn't figured out how the other question answers sorting a suggestion based on user defined priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47962. The fix is in progress.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is a bug. I've added my vote